# case statement to find if qualification has expired

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to workout if someone's qualification has expired. Once someone has completed a course it expires in 3 years from the date of completion.  If their qual has expired but they have a nominated date then that will count as being valid

What I currently have

```
EmployeeID     course        Completed Date        Nominated

    1           IT             2021-06-18
    2           IT             2020-10-10
    3           IT             2017-01-01
    4           IT             2017-01-01       2022-05-01
```

What I would like

```
EmployeeID     course         Completed Date    Nominated    Expiry          Valid 

    1           IT             2021-06-18                    2024-06-18       Yes
    2           IT             2020-10-10                    2023-10-10       Yes
    3           IT             2017-01-01                    2020-01-01       No
    4           IT             2017-01-01     2022-05-01                      Yes
```

I've managed to create the expiry column, need help with the 'Valid' case statement

```
cast(dateadd(year,3 ,[Completed_Date]) as date) as [Expiry]
```

Comment: The version of SSMS you're using is irrelevant to the version of SQL Server you are using, which is far more important. SSMS 2012 supported SQL Server 2005-2012. What version of SQL Server are you using? Though of the versions SSMS 2012 supported, all but 2012 is completely unsupported, and 2012 is close to running completely out of support. Also, T-SQL doesn't support `Case` (`Switch`) statements, just `CASE` expressions.

Comment: SQL server 2012

Comment: Is this logic really correct? If nominated is any value other than null (e.g., from 4 years ago) you want to still consider that row as valid?

Comment: For now it is, the example I've provided isn't the exact truth,  but if someone can give me a  kick start  and answer what I've asked it will help me on my way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `cross apply` for DRY and `case` expressions:

```
select t.*, expiry, case
    when nominated >= currdate then 'yes'
    when expiry >= currdate then 'yes'
    else 'no'
end as valid
from t
cross apply (select
    cast(current_timestamp as date),
    dateadd(year, 3, completed_date)
) as ca(currdate, expiry)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `Subquery` and `iif`to get your desired result,first use following query to produce

your data

```
declare @a TABLE(
  EmployeeID Int NOT NULL, 
  course VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
  completed_date Date, 
  Nominated Date
);
INSERT INTO @A(
  EmployeeID, course, completed_date, Nominated
) 
VALUES 
  (1, 'IT', '2021-06-18', NULL), 
  (2, 'IT', '2020-10-10', NULL), 
  (3, 'IT', '2017-01-01', NULL), 
  (4, 'IT', '2017-01-01', '2022-05-01');
```

`Expiray` column as
follows

```
 Iif(nominated IS NULL, Cast(Dateadd(year, 3, completed_date) AS DATE),
               NULL)
                      AS
               [Expiry]
```

then use subquery as follows

```
SELECT employeeid,
       course,
       completed_date,
       nominated,
       expiry,
       Iif(expiry < Getdate()
            OR nominated < Getdate(), 'No', 'Yes') valid
FROM   (SELECT employeeid,
               course,
               completed_date,
               nominated,
               Iif(nominated IS NULL, Cast(Dateadd(year, 3, completed_date) AS DATE),
               NULL)
                      AS
               [Expiry]
        FROM   @a) B
```